# Bluetooth module not loaded sometimes on reboot in Raspbian Buster, Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: linux, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, embedded-linux, raspbian

I have written a bluez application on Raspbian Buster, Raspberry Pi 4. In some reboots, the bluetooth module and service are not loaded.

On checking the bluetooth.service with command: `$ sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service`,
I see, `Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped`.

I checked `$ lsmod` and `$ dmesg` logs for both issue and non-issue conditions.

The difference I find in the lsmod is shown below:
[image: lsmod diff]

The difference I find in the dmesg log is shown below:
[image: dmesg diff]

*The left side is the issue case and the right side is non issue case.*

How can I fix the issue so that the bluetooth works consistently?
I am using [Raspbian Lite OS 2020-02-14](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_lite/images/raspbian_lite-2020-02-14/).

*Update 1 [03 Feb 2021]: I checked the journalctl log for the issue case and found this:*

```
Feb 03 11:52:18 pi btuart[373]: Failed to reset chip, invalid HCI event
Feb 03 11:52:18 pi btuart[373]: Can't initialize device: Success
Feb 03 11:52:18 pi btuart[373]: bcm43xx_init
Feb 03 11:52:18 pi systemd[1]: hciuart.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 03 11:52:18 pi systemd[1]: hciuart.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 03 11:52:18 pi systemd[1]: Failed to start Configure Bluetooth Modems connected by UART.
```

*Update 2 [03 Feb 2021]: My /boot/config.txt contents:*

```
dtparam=i2c_arm=on

dtparam=spi=on
dtoverlay=mcp2515-can0,oscillator=8000000,interrupt=25
dtoverlay=spi1-1cs

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

[pi4]
# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver on top of the dispmanx display stack
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

[all]
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d

disable_splash=1
enable_uart=1
max_usb_current=1

dtoverlay=uart2
dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds3231
gpu_mem=256
```

*My cmdline.txt contents:*

```
console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=738a4d67-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait logo.nologo vt.global_cursor_default=0 consoleblank=1 loglevel=1 quiet
```

Comment: Have you set your wifi country? If not, rfkill may be used to attempt disabling the on-board wifi networking hardware (to comply with international law). The hardware it would try to disable may the combined wifi+bluetooth radio.

Comment: @svin83 Wifi is working fine. The wifi is connected and I am able to SSH into it.

Comment: But have you set it? Look at the line containing "rfkill" and "cfg80211".

Comment: Which changes (if any) have you made to your "/boot/config.txt"  and "/boot/cmdline.txt" files?

Comment: Added the contents of config.txt and cmdline.txt .

Comment: This may require even more info to fix in a helpful manner... Like what hardware you have connected that require those changes to the device tree... I bet those non-default UART settings in your config.txt is part of the problem since the default bluetooth config expects the default UART...

Comment: @svin83 You were right. Based on this documentation: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/uart.md , I decided that UART2 in Raspberry Pi 4 is not used by bluetooth, which is why I interfaced my sensor in UART2. But, after not enabling the UART2 dtoverlay, I rebooted the Pi4 10 times and it worked properly after that. I will try to interface the sensor in some other interface, most probably an alternative I2C bus in RPi4 which does not have the clock stretching issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My orientation sensor was interfaced to UART2 of Raspberry Pi 4. On getting suggestion from @svin83 , I disabled UART2. After that I rebooted the Pi 4 10 times and the bluetooth worked correctly all the times.

I moved the sensor to I2C-3 bus in Raspberry Pi 4.

As per the documentation, [UART Configuration](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/uart.md), the UART2 should not have interfered with bluetooth functionality, but it turns out it does.